# MSVC 1900 and define vsnprintf

Tags: c, visual-c++, printf

I have a problem with a define inside my C code : for tests purpose, I need to define `vsnprintf` to `_tests_vsnprintf` during compilation like :

```
gcc -Dvsnprintf=_tests_vsnprintf file.c
```

This allow me to return an error from a `vsnpintf` call, in order to test the error management in my app. It works great on Linux, but does not build on Windows, MSVC 1900 (Visual Studio 2015) complains about macro redefinition ([C1189](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/y0tzt8e0(v=vs.71).aspx)).

The error come from this code in `stdio.h` :

```
  #if defined vsnprintf
        ...
    #error Macro definition of vsnprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
  #endif
```

I dont know how to get rid of the error with the minimal number of modifications.

Could you help me ?

Comment: Defining names of the standard library invokes undefined behaviour. They are reserved for the implementation. So are names starting with underscore at file-level. Briefly: You are not allowed to do this and gcc "eating" this is just by chance (it is not guaranteed to work as you expect, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in VC header specifically prevents you from doing this:

```
#if defined vsnprintf
    // This definition of vsnprintf will generate "warning C4005: 'vsnprintf': macro
    // redefinition" with a subsequent line indicating where the previous definition
    // of vsnprintf was.  This makes it easier to find where vsnprintf was defined.
    #pragma warning(push, 1)
    #pragma warning(1: 4005)
    #define vsnprintf Do not define vsnprintf as a macro
    #pragma warning(pop)
    #error Macro definition of vsnprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
#endif
```

As @Olaf mentioned, you might run into issues with library code if you redefine standard function. However if you only limit this to your code and ensure new definition is not picked up by any of the standard headers, you should be able to do `#define vsnprintf` **after** you included `<stdio.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define vsnptrintf my_test_vsnprintf
```